# Add numbers from dynamic site with new page load

Tags: javascript

How do you write a function/ listener in javascript that can fire when html updates?

- html page is limited to the last 100 records
- html page continuously adds new records (nodes)

I need to...

- push the values into an array or increment a variable to sum the values
- display the **running total** in html

Trying to create a counter that adds new values to the sum.

I believe the code below only executes once.

```
window.onload = function() {
var data = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var len = data.length;
var total = 0;
var searchValue = "value";

for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    var styles = data[i].getAttribute('style');
    if (styles == searchValue) {
    var txt = data[i].innerHTML;
    split = txt.split(" ");
    total += parseInt(split[2]);
    }   
    } 
console.log(total);
};
```

Comment: Make ajax request, parse response, apply format, display.  No persistent storage necessary.  You'd be better going and trying it then posting back any *specific* code blocks you get stuck on as your "question" is at the moment just an idea and ideas don't generally meet the SO QA format.

Comment: @Emissary, ajax requires a server correct? Is there a way to do this with just the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, where is your "dynamic feed" located?

Comment: I'm trying to add values from another site.

Comment: What site? If you don't have control over it - for the most robust solution (if any) you will likely be better parsing it server-side.  Very little information to go on though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this with just JavaScript, and a little HTML/CSS for displaying the number.

Note that it requires a fair deal of experience to manage an addon with cross-origin requests, and to show it to the user.

Comment: I'm using the add-on SDK and was thinking of using a "panel" which is just an html file. Can you point me in the direction of a cross-origin request example?

Comment: Just search "mdn add-on cross origin" or similar.

Comment: Would jquery be a better fit for this? Is there any way besides setInterval to get this total?